# android:isScrollContainer correct usage

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a LinearLayout that I want to make scrollable and therefore decided to give `android:isScrollContainer="true"` a try but its not scrolling as it is supposedly should.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/id_hour_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hh"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/id_min_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:text="mm"/>

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/id_sec_picker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:text="ss"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout in action:

[image]

You can see how its wrapping to the right hand side. I tried scrolling it and its not scrolling.

What might be wrong with the `android:isScrollContainer="true"` flag? Am I not using it correctly?

Comment: @Thunder : I can do that and have always done that but was wondering if this flag could solve the purpose without introducing a nested hierarchy

Comment: @Thunder : Not true: https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/what-does-android-isscrollcontainer-do-scrollview-textview-edittext